# Angular not getting data when browser and postman are

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework, cors

I have an API developed in Django Rest Framework which works when called in my browser and with postman but gives a "(Failed)" response when called in Angular. Doesn't give a response code (eg 404)

In the console log it claims its due to CORS but the same browser allows it then called directly.

Getting:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/article/articletype' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I know from the Django console that a call is being made successfully as it gives a 200 response.

I have tried allowing CORS to bypass from both ends by adding headers to the Angular calls. The below is the Access-Control's I have permitted. 
I've also played with different Content-Types and Accepts (was text/html) but now listing as *

```
'Accept' : '*/*' , 'Content-Type': '*' , 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'*'
```

For Django I have added the 'corsheaders' plugin with `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True`

I have also tried returning HttpResponse of the JSON and JsonResponse in Django.

In Django RFW:

Currently the code looks like this but I have tried lots of different iterations

```
jresponse = {
        "id" : 2,
        "text" : response,
        "prev_button" : "...prev",
        "subject1" : "SomeSub",
        "stage" : "SomeStage",
        "type1" : "SomeType1",
        "type2" : "SomeType2",
        "subject_list" : ["Sub1","Sub2","Sub3","Sub4"],
        "stage_list" : ["Stage1","Stage2","Stage3","Stage4"],
        "type1_list" : ["Type1.1","Type1.2", "Type1.3","Type1.4"],
        "type2_list" : ["Type2.1","Type2.2","Type2.3","Type2.4"],
    }

    jr=json.dumps(jresponse)
    jr['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    jr['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
    # jr = serialize('json', response) # Tried this, didn't work
    # return JsonResponse(jresponse) # Tried this, didn't work
    return HttpResponse(jresponse) # I have also tried returning the 'jr' variable
```

With all my iterations I usually get the response in the browser.

For Angular:

```
  getArticles() { 
    let add = 'http://localhost:8000/page/'.concat(this.articleid);
    this.http.get(add, 
      {headers : { 'Accept' : '*/*' , 'Content-Type': '*' , 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'*' }}
      ).subscribe(
      article => { this.article = article;
        console.log(this.article)
      })
```

As mentioned before the Accept and Content-Type have been through the mill.

I want Angular to receive the Json object to I can use in the template

eg: `{{article.subject}}`

Comment: Do you have the CORS middleware configured correctly? (Before the common middleware)

Comment: GET requests do not perform a pre-flight CORS check. The error in your question is for "http://localhost:8000/article/articletype" but your code is not accessing that URL

Answer (score 0):

Updated your settings like:

First Add your Angular URL to `allowed hosts`

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', 'other IP of servers']
```

and then check you `middleware` settings like:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

And then add below settings:

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True


CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:4200',
    'localhost:8000',
    '127.0.0.1:8000',
    'other IPs'
)

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
)

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = (
    '127.0.0.1:9200',
    'localhost:9200',
    'other IPs'
)

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
)
```

I face the same issue with angular and then I added settings like above then it worked.

Comment: There's actually no need to add the client's server domain to allowed hosts. It's just for the Django server

Comment: Tried the above to no joy.

Comment: Tried the above to no joy.

I've also added the headers with:
res = HttpResponse(jr)
res['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
return HttpResponse(jr)

With no avail. 

What is the handshake process with django?